# XCode 5.1 Simulator - Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate'

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storyboard Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628383/storyboard-could-not-instantiate-class-named-uistoryboardunwindseguetemplate-cra)

As with this question [Storyboard Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628383/storyboard-could-not-instantiate-class-named-uistoryboardunwindseguetemplate-cra) I have just finished the iOS Developer Library storyboard tutorial and ran it on iPhone 5.1 Simulator.

It works fine until I hit the Add button, and it simply crashes with the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate'

When I switch to iPhone 6.0 Simulator it works perfectly as expected.

The answer in the question I referenced is the same code I have copied from the tutorial, so I'm at a loss as **how to "downgrade" the code to work with 5.1, or if it's possible.**

This is my first time using Storyboard and as far as I can tell the only code connecting the modal add view is the Storyboard "Modal segue from Add to Navigation Controller".

(this is also my first question on stackoverflow so I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough)

The full tutorial code is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CodeListings/CodeListings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH9-SW1

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer in the question that *you linked to*?

Comment: The answer in the question I linked to includes the same code from the tutorial I was following. I also tried adding IBAction buttons to replace the unwind segue but I get this error '-[AddSightingViewController cancel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c96270'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIStoryboardUnwindSegue class was introduced since iOS 6.0, you can't use it in iOS 5... You have to use for example: delegate, for perform unwind action.

Comment: How do I go about performing an unwind action for iOS 5.1?

Comment: You can't! This feature is only available in iOS6. You can use for example: - (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated .

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure what to call it other than an "unwind action", as that's what you referred to it as well. Thank you, that is very helpful.